# How to make LEFT OUTER JOIN except some colums?

Tags: mysql, sql, wampserver

I have 3 tables:

First "placement"
[image]

Second "user_info"

[image]

Third "user_placements"

[image]

I want to get all placement data with user infos,

[image]

**How to do it?**

I tried this, but result it not what I expected:

```
SELECT *, user_placements.id AS user_placements_id, placement.id AS placement_id
FROM placement
LEFT OUTER JOIN user_placements ON placement.id = user_placements.id_placement
```

Comment: Just list those fields between the select and the from that you want to include in the resultset. And also join all 3 tables, not just 2.

Comment: there is any relation between user_placements and user_info or placement and user_info  ?

Comment: @krishnpatel `user_info.id = user_placements.id_user` and `placement.id = user_placements.id_placement`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to one more join with user info

```
SELECT placement.*,user_info.id as user_info_id,user_info.name as user_name,user_info.mobile as user_mobile
 FROM placement LEFT OUTER JOIN user_placements ON placement.id = user_placements.id_placement
    LEFT OUTER JOIN user_info ON user_info.id = user_placements.id_user
```

Comment: It's great, but in result there is two columns "id" , one from  `placement`, and second from `user_info`

Comment: yes it will be if you want different you should write different way

Comment: Is any way to use operator "AS" to rename them?

Comment: see I have done for user_info if you want to change for placement you can do it now

Comment: What if my user_info will have a lot of fields? Then how to rename "id" field by using operator "AS"?

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the second join:

```
SELECT *
FROM placement AS p
JOIN user_placements AS up ON p.id = up.id_placement
JOIN user_info AS u ON up.id_user = u.id
```

Replace the wildcard with the data you want. 
You will of course get duplicated data with this query.